# How can I have redirection link from google news link using requests?

Tags: python, redirect, python-requests

I hope to get the redirected link from the original link as follows:

[origin url]
https://news.google.com/rss/articles/CBMiNWh0dHBzOi8vd3d3LmhhbmkuY28ua3IvYXJ0aS9jdWx0dXJlL2Jvb2svMTA4ODU4OC5odG1s0gEA?oc=5

--> [Redirection url]
https://m.hani.co.kr/arti/culture/book/1088588.html

To do this, I wrote the code below:

```
import requests

link = "https://news.google.com/rss/articles/CBMiNWh0dHBzOi8vd3d3LmhhbmkuY28ua3IvYXJ0aS9jdWx0dXJlL2Jvb2svMTA4ODU4OC5odG1s0gEA?oc=5"

r = requests.get(link)
print(r.url)
```

Almost links are OK, But I get an error for some links as below. What could be the reason?

```
link = "https://news.google.com/rss/articles/CBMiK2h0dHBzOi8vemRuZXQuY28ua3Ivdmlldy8_bm89MjAyMzA0MTYxMTA1NDnSAQA?oc=5"
```

How can we fix the code to get redirection url?

[origin url]
https://news.google.com/rss/articles/CBMiK2h0dHBzOi8vemRuZXQuY28ua3Ivdmlldy8_bm89MjAyMzA0MTYxMTA1NDnSAQA?oc=5

--> [Redirection url]
https://zdnet.co.kr/view/?no=20230416110549

Answer (score 2):

Try to set right cookies/HTTP headers and then parse the response with HTML parser for the link:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://news.google.com/rss/articles/CBMiK2h0dHBzOi8vemRuZXQuY28ua3Ivdmlldy8_bm89MjAyMzA0MTYxMTA1NDnSAQA?oc=5'
headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/108.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'
}

cookies = {'CONSENT': 'YES+cb.20220419-08-p0.cs+FX+111'}

r = requests.get(url, headers=headers, cookies=cookies)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
print(soup.a['href'])
```

Prints:

```
https://zdnet.co.kr/view/?no=20230416110549
```